# Exctracting more than one field at time from a JSon file

Tags: java, android, json

I was developing a simple application that exctracts some fields of a JSon that tells me in real time what weather is in that exact moment, and I have exctracted only one filed, and I was asking myself: Is it possible to extract more than on field at time?

Here is the the link from where i parse the Json:

https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat=35&lon=139

And here's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btnHit;
TextView txtJson;
ProgressDialog pd;
ArrayMap<Integer, String> arrayMap = new ArrayMap<>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnHit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnHit);
    txtJson = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvJsonItem);

    btnHit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new JsonTask().execute("https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat=35&lon=139");
        }
    });


}


public class JsonTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pd.setMessage("Please wait");
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();


            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
                Log.d("Response: ", "> " + line);

            }

            return buffer.toString();


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (pd.isShowing()) {
            pd.dismiss();
        }


        try {
            JSONObject Object = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(Object.getString("weather"));


            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonPart = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                //txtJson.append("main: " + jsonPart.getString("main") + '\n');
                arrayMap.put(i, jsonPart.getString("main"));
                txtJson.append("main: " + arrayMap.get(i) + '\n');

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //txtJson.setText(result);
        }

        //txtJson.setText(result);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Use `Retrofit` and `Gson` converter for this rather than `HttpUrlConnection` and whatnot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to extract other object alongwith main from the array weather

```
"weather": [
    {
      "id": 701,
      "main": "Mist",
      "description": "mist",
      "icon": "https://cdn.glitch.com/6e8889e5-7a72-48f0-a061-863548450de5%2F50n.png?1499366021876"
    }
```

If that is the requirement then you can use the same process like you have done just change the name of the object.

```
arrayMap.put(i, jsonPart.getString("description"));
```

or 
you can use gson and convert the object in pojo class in one go. Then use the object of the pojo and access the data.

Hope it helps.